# Run graphical application only in remote machine using Java JSch, no using X11Fordward

Tags: java, ssh, remote-access, jsch

I want to run an remote graphical application in any OS with JSch that only runs in that remote machine, for example I want to run gedit (Ubuntu) and it will appears in the desktop machine, i don't need to use it in the shell of SSH, it's like a remote launcher.

Is it possible to use any option for that?

```
/*Adding an option in session that allow this...*/
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
channelExec.setCommand("gedit"); //channelExec.setCommand("notepad");
```

Comment: `ssh -Y` *is* X11 forwarding.. Your question isn't clear. You want the X11 application to run on the ssh server's display?

Comment: sorry i dont know that option -Y is X11 forwarding, i will edit my question, what i want is to run the remote graphics application but that only run on that machine and not on my ssh console (ie run gedit and then appears on the desktop of the Ubuntu where I connect with shh), only launch it not using it in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `DISPLAY=localhost:0`, although you might have problems with security; if so, please update the question.

Comment: how i can set this in Jsch and is possible to use this in windows OS too? thanks for your reply.

Comment: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html has an example of how to set an environment variable using `setEnv`. Which OS is windows? If the ssh server, it should be ok if you're running an X server e.g. Cygwin/x

Comment: any windows os like windows 7 or XP, maybe installing openSSH?

Comment: Finally i got it, i use ChannelShell and i use the command: `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` and then i can run any graphical application in that Desktop, the setEnv dont work for me, but this way works, at least for Linux i will test in windows.

Comment: how did you achieve that @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci I want to do also but I could not understand which method you used?